# How to insert value in c++ map std::map<string , list<string> in c++?

Tags: list, c++11, dictionary, std-pair

I am trying to insert a value in map where key to map is string and value is list.
When I try to insert then I am getting error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
main()
{
     string key = "myKey";
     string str1 = "str1";

     map<string, list<string>> myMap;
     myMap.insert( make_pair (key, str1));

 }
```

error

Error 2 error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>     std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair &&)' :
    cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&'

Help is appreciated !!

Comment: Note `std::map` has been introduced prior to C++11

Comment: Why not use `multimap` or `unordered_multimap`?

Answer (score 3):

You have a `std::map` that takes a key which is a string and a list as value.
You are trying to pass it a key that is a string and a string as value which is the problem.

```
main()
{
     string key = "myKey";
     string str1 = "str1";
     list<string> l;

     l.push_back( str1 );

     map<string, list<string>> myMap;
     myMap.insert( make_pair (key, l)); // pass a list here

    return 0;
}
```